# Cygwin is telling me a file doesn't exist when it does

Tags: linux, file, cygwin, cp

I'm trying to copy some files to set up Giza++ in Cygwin with the command

```
cp ~/mosesdecoder/giza-pp/GIZA++-v2/GIZA++ ~/mosesdecoder/giza-pp/GIZA++-v2/snt2cooc.out \~/mosesdecoder/giza-pp/mkcls-v2/mkcls.cpp tools
```

However when I run it, I get the error

```
cp: cannot stat '~/mosesdecoder/giza-pp/mkcls-v2/mkcls.cpp': No such file or directory
```

I know this file exists and I don't know why it's telling me it doesn't. In fact, when I run

```
cygstart ~/mosesdecoder/giza-pp/mkcls-v2/mkcls.cpp
```

The file opens and runs fine. Does anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a backslash in front of one of your tildes (~), causing the shell to take it literally; this is not what you want.

Comment: Wow I can't believe I missed something as simple as that. thank you